# DataGridView in foreach loop

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to simplify this code:

```
DataGridViewColumn column1 = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
column1.Width = 300;
DataGridViewColumn column2 = dataGridView2.Columns[0];
column2.Width = 300;
```

by putting it info a foreach loop. I tried this:

```
foreach (DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
{
DataGridViewColumn column = dgv.Columns[0];
column.Width = 300;
}
```

I didn't work - do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Your code is correct, what's the problem ? is the code not work for all `DataGridView` ?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't work for all DataGridViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over the Columns collection of your DataGridView

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
     column.Width = 300;
```

if you need to loop only over the first two columns then

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns
                                                   .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                                   .Take(2))
     column.Width = 300;
```

or for all DataGridViews in your form

```
foreach(DataGridView dgv in this.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
     foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
         column.Width = 300;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for all DataGridViews (works only for dataGridView1).

Comment: If you have more than a DataGridView in the same form then you just add a first loop over the controls of type DataGridView. Instead if you want a generic method that is callable for any DataGridView in your application then you need to pass the DataGridView to format at the generic method. Could you explain what is your objective?